# How to customise React-Day-Picker input?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-day-picker

Here is my code

```
<DayPickerInput 
   placeholder={"Date..."} 
   onDayChange={day => setNewDate(day)}
   className="day"
/>
```

```
.day {
  text-align: center;
  text-size-adjust: 100;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: var(--bg-accent);
  color: var(--text-color);
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

but all of this isn't affecting the day picker input. How would I for example change the background of the day picker?

Comment: Inspect the source and see which element the `day` class is actually applied to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific class defined for the input field from the package react-day-picker, but we could get the DOM structure as you could see that it's right down the class `DayPickerInput`

```
<div class="DayPickerInput">
  <input placeholder="YYYY-M-D" value="">
</div>
```

[image]

so the only thing left to do is to use a **CSS element selector**

```
.DayPickerInput > input {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is helpful but is it possible to edit the dropdown? I looked into the DOM structure but I couldn't find where the background is because there's a lot of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `DayPickerInput` doesn't support custom classes, try to use default `.DayPickerInput` className.